# Corda node does not start and giving error Failure in initialisation errorCode 1gariof

Tags: java, kotlin, blockchain, corda

I am running the very first example of Corda. I followed all the steps [here](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html) but whenever I run nodes using runnodes or running single node by going inside nodes folder

```
cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes\PartyA>java -jar corda.jar
```

it returns me the error as follows

```
D:\WORK\cryptocurrency and blockchain\Trainings-Certs\Corda\cordapp_experiments\corda_dapp_Samples\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes\PartyA>java -jar corda.jar

   ______               __
  / ____/     _________/ /___ _
 / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/         It runs on the JVM because QuickBasic
/ /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /          is apparently not 'professional' enough.
\____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/

--- Corda Open Source 4.0 (503a2ff) -------------------------------------------------------------


Logs can be found in                    : D:\WORK\Corda\cordapp_experiments\corda_dapp_Samples\cordapp-example\workflows-java\build\nodes\PartyA\logs
! ATTENTION: This node is running in development mode!  This is not safe for production deployment.
Advertised P2P messaging addresses      : localhost:10004
RPC connection address                  : localhost:10005
RPC admin connection address            : localhost:10006
[ERROR] 11:18:34+0300 [main] core.server.run - AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation [errorCode=1gariof, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/1gariof]
Shutting down ...
[ERROR] 11:18:35+0300 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Failed to bind on address localhost:10004.
```

My configurations are:

- Windows 10
- Java Version :  java version "1.8.0_211"

The `gradlew.bat deployNodes` command has generated all the nodes successfully but when I reached to runnodes command and called `workflows-kotlin\build\nodes\runnodes.bat` then output terminal window displays that all nodes are running successfully. However, the four new windows immediately open and close with the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that it cannot bind to `localhost:10004` normally that is due to another process running that has already claimed the port.

Check what other processes are running that could be taking the port.

In regards to corda, if you check the `deployNodes` script in the examples root directory. You will see that it creates a few nodes and in the configuration takes in a number of ports for each node to use. You can change these port values if needed.

Comment: I did netstat -a -b on the windows and found for some reason java was using all ports from 10004 to 10 , so I restarted and ran the node and it worked. Thanks for the help